How can I do Device to Device communication using Azure
I'm trying to communicate two devices let us assume Device A and Device B. According to the documentations online and references online we can do the following methods as per my understanding.

Use IoT Hub to connect with devices -> Device A send telemetry to IoT Hub -> use function apps to route the data -> Again by using Client to device in IoT Hub send back to device 2. Reference Link

User Event Grid. Event grid is an MQTT and HTTP Supported Azure service that acts as a MQTT Broker and can perform Pub/Sub Mechanism. Link


Question - 1:
Now let us say I have implemented the device telemetry sending through IoT Hub and I dont want to change it. Now how can I implement scalable Device to Device Communication. The ultimate solution is to change to event grid itself? or is there any other way of executing this?
Question - 2:
If not IoT Hub, what is the best possible way to implement the architecture.
As I am very new to Azure please do apologize If my question is not understandable. Please feel free to comment will clarify any doubts regarding the question.
I tried to send data from ESP8266 taking an example from Azure SDK for C and it went well. I am trying to find subscribe mechanism where I need to get data back to other ESP8266 or Python Module.

For this device-to-device communication, the Azure Event Grid MQTT broker is the simplest cloud-based solution. Device A can publish to an MQTT topic, and Device B can subscribe to the topic.
If you want to use IoT Hub, you'll need to configure IoT Hub routing to send messages from Device A another service such as Azure Functions that can generate cloud-to-device messages to send to Device B.
Have you considered running an MQTT broker on the edge rather than in the cloud? For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-operations/manage-mqtt-connectivity/overview-iot-mq

Thank you for giving the clarification, Dominic. I have one more question regarding the second point you mentioned, Sending to destination by using function apps also mean that it's point to point, right, If I wanted Pub/Sub with IoT Hub in scope, Then the solution might look like Device A Publish to Telemetry-> (IoT Hub) -> (Event Grid through Routing) -> Device B or C or D, Subscribe to Topic Telemetry and they get the data?

If you want pub/sub with IoT Hub in scope, then your proposed route would work. I would ask why you want to keep IoT Hub in scope - if you want pub/sub using a cloud MQTT broker why not just use Azure Event Grid?

Thank you for the confirmation, Diminic, as for your question, It is because I want to use IoT Hub capabilities of communicating through the Security Key. If I use MQTT alone, I don't think so there might be any security ultimately leading my data secure free. This is what I think about, and I am open for any other suggestions as well if I am wrong. Apologies for the delayed reply.

And also as mentioned: here Microsoft is insisting on using IoT Hub for IoT Device connectivity. So, I am thinking to go with IoT Hub Integrated to Events Grid.

@SaiKalyan Be careful not to confuse Azure Event Hubs with Azure Event Grid - the article you reference in your last comment discusses Azure Event Hubs - this is not the same as the MQTT broker in Azure Event Grid which is intended device connectivity.

My bad sorry for that I wanted to insist on why IoT Hub is important in my application. As I mentioned earlier, I will try out with IoT Hub integrated event grid and will see what happens. Thank you very much for your help.
